# How to check if a property is null in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am here with a basic question. If I directly compare variables then I can get defined results.
But I can not check if a passed value as property is null or undefined. Because it is showing never as null or undefined. So conditional checking not working. So please advice me, how to check if a property is undefined or null.

```
import { memo, useRef } from "react"; 

const MyComponent = (myList) => {
  const renderTimes = useRef(0);

  return (
    <div>
      {renderTimes.current++}

      <div>Rendered : {renderTimes.current} times.</div>
 

      {console.log(
        "block. Is it null? : ",
        myList === null,
        " is it undefined ? ",
        myList === undefined,
        "Check type:",
        typeof myList === "undefined"
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

[image]

```
<MyComponent myList={undefined} />
```

If I pass nothing or even I passed named property as null and undefined both the time it shows same result.

Comment: The first argument of a component are its [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html). If you want the actual value you can either [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) `({ myList })` or use `props.myList`

Comment: Thanks for replying. I forgot about that, will try. Well still a question why it should be not null when it is not defined?

Comment: Because there are lots of things it can be that aren't `null` or `undefined`, in this case it is the props object.

Comment: even with `({myList})`, it still shows as not null, but it shows as undefined. even if I pass `<MyComponent myList={null}>`.

Comment: Of corse you have object like `{myList: undefined}`, it's not equal `null` or `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

You can modify modify your code as such :

```html
import { memo, useRef } from "react"; 

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const renderTimes = useRef(0);
  
  // Checks if the "myList" element is defined
  if(this.props.myList === undefined) {
    console.log('myList is not defined')
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      {renderTimes.current++}

      <div>Rendered : {renderTimes.current} times.</div>
 

      {console.log(
        "block. Is it null? : ",
        {{ props.myList }} === null,
        " is it undefined ? ",
        {{ props.myList }} === undefined,
        "Check type:",
        typeof {{ props.myList }} === "undefined"
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

In short:  **your 'myList' variable is actually the props object** - it would never show a null / undefined value (as it's an object).

The right way to pass values to components (from a parent component) is via the props object.  At the child component, you get them using this way (**NOTE: without *this.* as this is a functional component**):

Using the example you supplied:

Parent comp (what you've done there was just fine):

```
<MyComponent myList = {...} />
```

Child comp:

```
{props.myList}
```

(Or without the brackets when used outside the return block.)

---

By the way, if you'd like to create a render counter, the right way to do that is performing the renderCounter++; command outside the return block (in which you will then display the updated variable), ie,

```
...

    renderTimes.current++;
  return (
    <div>
      {renderTimes.current}

...
```

I think you might be getting wrong outputs from the counter this way, not sure though.

Remember that useRef() does not re-render the component, while useState() does (I don't know what exactly you were trying to achieve there, I'm just mentioning it fwiw.